# Simple JSF Ajax Command Button rerender not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, render, commandbutton

I'm having a lot of problems with implementing an Ajax call to my Managed Bean.  I prepared a simple test case - I expect the outputText value to change to Beta, but it remains at Alpha.  What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.controllers;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "tester")
@ViewScoped
public class tester{

    private String testString;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of tester
     */
    public tester() {
        testString = "Alpha";
    }

    public String changeText(){

        testString = "Beta";
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the testString
     */
    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    /**
     * @param testString the testString to set
     */
    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Add Row" action="#{tester.changeText}">
                <f:ajax event="action" execute="@form" render="out"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:outputText id="out" value="#{tester.testString}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix CDI with managed beans. Change `import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` to  to `import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

**UPDATE** 
From your comment it seems that you do not have JSF 2.2 (my mistake). Easiest thing for you to do would be the following:

Replace

```
import javax.inject.Named
```

with

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

and

```
@Named(value = "tester")
```

with

```
@ManagedBean(name = "tester")
```

One last thing, you do not have to specify a value for `name` when you do the changes above. When you use `@ManagedBean` without the `name` you can refer to your bean in your xhtml pages by using the class name. Keep in mind though that the first letter will be in lower case.

Comment: Netbeans doesn't seem to recognize that import, are you sure it's right?

Comment: @tacua Makes sense or no ? I can expand if needed.

Comment: I got it working with changing to Managed Beans, thanks!  My teacher says I should work with CDI though, so I need to read up on the differences between the two.

Comment: @tacua It's simple really. CDI will ignore all annotations from the package `javax.faces.bean.*` It has its own package when it comes to scopes `import javax.enterprise.context.*` There's more to CDI (they are more powerful) but that should suffice for now ;)